# Async method in Vuejs mixin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to reuse a method in multiple vuejs component. I'm using mixin to do this but async method is not working

I have a async method in mixin that wait for an axios call `GET-AllDrafts` to finish and then run a mutation that updated the draft state value to the returned data from axios call.

```
async orgUpdateMixin() {
      await this.$store.dispatch('GET_AllDrafts')
                       .then(data => {                                       
                           this.$store.commit('draftUpdate', data);    //mutation                                              
                     })
}
```

I'm running this method in `mounted()` method of my component.

```
mounted(){
   this.orgUpdateMixin();
   console.log(this.data);
}
```

But for some reason this.data is returning [] empty array. Is there a way to wait for mixin to finish first before continuing.

Comment: What about doing `await this.orgUpdateMixin();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, do:

```
async mounted() {
  await this.orgUpdateMixin();
  console.log(this.data);
}
```

Comment: mounted cannot be async by vuejs v2.6